# Deploy to $CATALINA_HOME using maven cargo plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, cargo

I use `cargo-maven2-plugin` to deploy `war` files to a running remote `tomcat` container. Now I need to copy files to `$CATALINA_HOME/myfolder`. I do this using `ant-run/scp/ssh`.

But is it possible to do this with the cargo-maven2-plugin or does it only operate on the application/webapps level?

Answer (score 0):

Try cargo with `installed` deployer and `existing` configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>existing</type>
            <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
        </configuration>
        <deployer>
            <type>installed</type>
        </deployer>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My sample project works this way

```
$ mvn cargo:deploy

[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.5:deploy (default-cli) @ sample-war ---
[INFO] [edDeployerDeployMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.4.5 for container tomcat7x
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [/home/mariuszs/git/sample-war/target/sample.war] to [/opt/tomcat/webapps]...
```

You can check full sample project for this https://github.com/mariuszs/cargo-existing-installed-sample

Some links than can help:

- [Local container](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Installed+Container)
- [Existing Local Configuration](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Existing+Local+Configuration)